# prove or disprove: There exists T : M2(R) → R3 which neither onto nor 1-1.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How to do this proof?
Prove or disprove: *There exists T : M2(R)  → R3 which neither onto nor 1-1.*
Can I do as following: 
dim(M2(R))=4, dim(R3)=3, dim(M2(R))>dim(R3),so T can be onto but it can't be 1-1. So the statement is true because T can also be not onto.

Comment: To prove the statement you will have to find an example. BTW: Did you forget to mention the tiny word "linear"?

Comment: What if $T$ takes any matrix to the zero vector?

Comment: the questions doesn't say if it is a linear transformation or not, but I think we can assume that.

Comment: Something a little more involved than the zero transformation: $T(A)=[A_{1,1},0,0]^{T}$.